# In what date format is 1339698600000 = 15 June 2012?

Tags: datetime, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) and get a value of 1339698600000 for the selected date of  15th June 2012.

What dateformat is this? How do I convert it to human readable format?

Is there any resource where I can find many more formats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the number of milliseconds since *January 1, 1970 (POSIX epoch)*. You can divide it by *1000* to get the number of seconds since *epoch* which is a standard way to represent time.

Comment: Or just trim off the last three digits

Comment: Or more specifically, it is the standard numeric form of a [JavaScript date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: I dont know how I missed it. I was getting a date of 6030 on epochconverter.com. It works correctly now. Strange. I think I need some sleep.

Comment: @Kaustubh P: I got it of the top of my head since I was wrestling with this same issue today, except I was missing _*1000_ instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970.  To convert to human readable, Add that many milliseconds to a 1/1/1970 date object.